# NGINX reverse_proxy with subpath and regex

Tags: nginx, regex

I have a site running on `localhost:8001` and I would like it to be accessible on different paths. I need to extract part of the path using regex.

This *does* work:

```
server {
    location /user/amy/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001/;
    }
}
```

(but it breaks if I remove the slash after `8001`).

However, the username can be dynamic, for example:

```
mydomain.com/user/amy/ --> localhost:8081/
mydomain.com/user/bob/foo --> localhost:8081/foo
```

In both cases I want to get the username out in order to do a subrequest. Here is what I have tried:

```
server {
    location ~ ^/user/([a-z]+)/(.*)$ {
        set $user $1; # do stuff with this later
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001/$2;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work: I get a *too many redirects* error. I've tried *many* things and nothing seems to work. I want it to work exactly like the prefix example I gave first, except that I extract the username for further processing. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you try Nginx Proxy Manager.

Comment: And so what? Explain how to do this using your "Nginx Proxy Manager".

Comment: You add a proxy host and then add custom locations. You will see the option in the Gui of Nginx Proxy Manager